# Custom Taxonomy as Link

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, functions, taxonomy

I have this image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA1SY.png which shows the download button I will be talking about.

I am trying to make it so that when I put in a custom taxonomy box in the back end the text of **example.com/download** the download button pulls the link and when you click it it directs you there sort of like the function `the_permalink` can anyone help me achieve this? Would be really greatful.

```
<a class="v2-button download-track" href="<?php the_custom_taxonomy(); ?>">
DOWNLOAD <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @s_ha_dum ;-; I need to know how to make a custom taxonomy but one for links and not just for text, or maybe for text will work if you can clear the default links behind it.

Comment: I think you mean custom *field* (post meta), not taxonomy (categories, tags, etc.)?